# How to design GUI to navigate through multiple hierarchies?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, multi-touch, tablet

I would like to design a GUI `dashboard` for a document management application. The `dashboard` contains only documents thumbnails. Each document may belong to a few hierarchies (e.g. "topic" hierarchy, "language" hierarchy, "genre" hierarchy, etc.) A user may want to select math texts in English, or lyrics in all Roman languages, etc.

How would you design a GUI for this ? What if the `dashboard` runs in a multi-touch tablet device ? What are examples of such GUI ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design.

Answer (score 2):

I sketched these examples that would work with mouse or touch:

**1) Dropdown Tags**: You can use a approach similar to what Delicious do with tags, but put tags under hierarchies which you can chose on dropdown menus right on the top. The documents are filtered on real time while you choose the filters. It would be interesting to save an old filters for quickly navigation.
[image: DropDown]

**2) CheckBox:** If you have few filter and options you can keep a bunch of checkbox on the side and filter the documents on real time:
[image: Checkbox]

However, it is hard to come with a UI like that, I think you should prototype and ask for the user to test what is better.

Answer (score 1):

When you design a UI interface, remember that the user has to know where they are in a system. They need to know what they can do next; and what will happen when they do it and get there.
The most intuitive GUI for any user will be one whose interface they're already familiar with.
This way, they won't have to spend time thinking about what would happen when they perform a certain action.

Browser UI's and File explorer UI's are some such examples.
Hovering on a file to see a semi-transparent pop-up which lists options of what to do with the file is another way to enhance usability without cluttering the screen with navigation aids. (this works even for multitouch screens)